# Subset and recombine dataframes using data.table package or other solutions [R]

Tags: r, data.table

I am quite new to R and have a question about subset and recombine between two dataframe using range value of one of the variable. So i have my two dataframes like this :

```
        x         y                         
 [1,] 79.00     19.63
 [2,] 79.01     19.58
 [3,] 79.02     19.57
 [4,] 79.03     19.58
 [5,] 79.04     19.60
 [6,] 79.05     19.65
 [7,] 79.06     19.67
 [8,] 79.07     19.70
 [9,] 79.08     19.67
[10,] 79.09     19.72
```

and

```
          id        min_x  max_x
[1,] 7G005-1010-10  79.01  79.06  
[2,] 7G100-0001-10  79.02  79.09
[3,] 8S010-1201-10  79.06  79.09
```

My purpose is to combine the two of them  like this:

```
     id           x       y
7G005-1010-10   79,01   19,58
7G005-1010-10   79,02   19,57
7G005-1010-10   79,03   19,58
7G005-1010-10   79,04   19,6
7G005-1010-10   79,05   19,65
7G005-1010-10   79,06   19,7
7G100-0001-10   79,02   19,57
     ...         ...     ...
```

As you can see on the output of my dataframes, i try to use the `data.table` package to find a way to solve my probleme.

Well, if anybody can tell me how deal with it (with or without `data.table`)!

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: So, you are trying to get id according to the range x falls into? If that's what you want then the ranges overlap! The first id overlaps the second and the second also overlaps the third. How do you deal with this?

Comment: Thank you for a very clear question with input and desired output! This is great. :)

Comment: using `data.table` version >=v1.9.8 (released to CRAN on Nov 25, 2016), one can perform a non-equi join using `DT1[DT2, on=.(x>=min_x, x<=max_x), nomatch=0L, .(id, x=x.x, y=x.y)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible in `data.table` nicely. It's [FR#203](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=203&group_id=240&atid=978) to implement. You could try package `xts` as I think that has this operation.

One long and clunky way (untested) in `data.table` is as follows. Say your first table is `P` and the 2nd table containing the ranges is `R`.

```
setkey(P,x)
# sort by x and mark as sorted so future queries can use binary search on P

from = P[J(R$min_x),which=TRUE]
# Lookup each min_x in the key of P, returning the location. J stands for Join.

to = P[J(R$max_x),which=TRUE]
# Lookup each max_x in the key of P, returning the location.

len = to-from+1
# vectorized for each item the length to[i]-from[i]+1

i = unlist(mapply("seq.int",from,to,SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# for each item the sequence from[i]:to[i], then concat them all into one vector

cbind(rep(R$id,len), P[i])
# use len to expand the items of R to match what they match to in P
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, and thank you very much for the advice. I will try it soon.

thank you again

Comment: I tried our code but I have an issue. I use a similar data.table to my post (like the first one). I have this message when I run the code with the setkey function
'Erreur dans setkeyv (P,x) : 
  Column 'x' cannot be coerced to integer without losing fractional data.'

I looked for the manual of data.table package but I can’t figure it out. Well ,if you can enlightened me .
Merci beaucoup !

Best regards.

Comment: @mat You'll need to upgrade to v1.8.1 by installing from the R-Forge repo. Apologies I should have mentioned that. Follow the link on the homepage. Allowing floating point ('numeric') in keys is new in v1.8.1. See recent presentation [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/LondonR_2012.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, your code work perfectly! I don't want to take advantage of your kindness but can you explain a little your code? 
I don’t understand all the subtleties. As I said I am a newbie to R and I want to improve my knowledges in this field.
One more time, thank a lot for your answers and for this excellent package that is data.table.
Best regards