# Equivalent to sql cartesian query with data.table

Tags: sql, r, data.table

Is there a way to get the equivalent in data.table to the following SQL query?

```
create C as select * from R,P where 
P.x between R.min_x and R.max_x and P.var2 < R.col3
```

My problem is that I cannot the the cartesian product of `R,P` as R would crash, I am happy with any technique (even if it is in several step...)

Typical size are R 1K rows, P 3M rows

EDIT:

```
library(data.table)
R = data.table(min_x=c(.6,.4,.01,.8),max_x=c(.7,.51,.05,.95),col3=c(.6,.4,1.2,.6))
P = data.table(x=seq(.1,.9,.1),var2=c(1,.4,.3,.2,0,.5,.65,.7,0))
setkey(P, x)
setkey(R,min_x,max_x) #and max_x is always > min_x

#R
#   min_x max_x col3
#1:  0.01  0.05  1.2
#2:  0.40  0.51  0.4
#3:  0.60  0.70  0.6
#4:  0.80  0.95  0.6

#B
#      x var2
#1:  0.1 1.00 => var1 not in any [col1,col2]
#2:  0.2 0.40 => same
#3:  0.3 0.30 => same
#4:  0.4 0.20 => .4 in [.4,.51] but .2 < .4 so NO
#5:  0.5    0 => same 
#6:  0.6 0.50 => .6 in [.6, .7] but .5 < .6 so NO
#7:  0.7 0.65 => .6 in [.6, .7] AND .65 > .6 => SELECTED
#8:  0.8 0.70 => YES
#9:  0.9    0 => NO
```

So expected result

```
#  min_x max_x  col3    x var2
#1: 0.60  0.70  0.6  0.70 0.65 
#2: 0.80  0.95  0.6  0.80 0.70
```

Comment: If you could explain what this is supposed to do with an example, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Usually, example = reproducible example with sample data that you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an answer with the help of @Matthew Dowle from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157172/subset-and-recombine-dataframes-using-data-table-package-or-other-solutions-r)

```
setkey(P,x)
# sort by x and mark as sorted so future queries can use binary search on P
# Lookup each min_x in the key of P, returning the location. J stands for Join.
from = P[J(R$min_x), roll=-Inf, mult='first', which=TRUE]
# Lookup each max_x in the key of P, returning the location.
to = P[J(R$max_x),roll=Inf, mult='last', which=TRUE]
# vectorized for each item the length to[i]-from[i]+1
len = to-from+1
#get NA that can occur if no x > min_x  
isNaFromTo = !is.na(from) & !is.na(to)
#remove the NA from from/to
to = to[isNaFromTo]
from = from[isNaFromTo]
#replace NA by 0 in len which will flag the fact that we want to remove the line from R
len[!isNaFromTo] = 0;
# create index for P
i = unlist(mapply("seq.int",from,to,SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# create index of R 
j = rep(1:nrow(R), len);
#bind to get the result
res = cbind(R[j], P[i]) 
res = res[var2>col3]
```

Result as expected

```
   min_x max_x col3   x var2
1:   0.6  0.70  0.6 0.7 0.65
2:   0.8  0.95  0.6 0.8 0.70
```

Answer (score 1):

When this FR is implemented (and its links may be useful) :

[FR#203 Allow 2 column to specify range in i instead of %between%](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=203&group_id=240&atid=978)

it might be :

```
setkey(B, var1, var2)
B[A[,list(.(col1,col2),.(-Inf,col3))], j]
```

If that sounds ok?  You would want to specify a `j` which would run per group (per row of `i`) to save a potential cartesian expansion in memory. But if you really wanted the large table returned, the `allow.cartesian` flag could be set :

```
B[A[,list(.(col1,col2),.(-Inf,col3))], allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

This can't be done right now of course, so this is just an exploratory answer.

Comment: I am sure about the syntax, because in this case `var1` and `var2` are compared to `(col1,col2)` and `(-Inf,col3)` so you can use `key` to know what is compared to what, but what if you have more than one comparaison for one variable ? (I guess you can always simplify...)

Comment: Also in my case to get things done do you think I should write a function with B as a global variable and extract the correct rows from it for each line of A ? => I'll check the links

Comment: @statquant Yep there's some hints in the linked Q&As. True enough about the syntax. `data.table` hasn't got to declarative syntax yet, it's imperative currently. Maybe one day...